# What is the equivalent of jQuery's $('*').css('font-size', '') in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-size

What is the equivalent of  jQuery's `$('*').css('font-size', '');` in JavaScript? I want to change font-size of every element on my website.

`document.body.style.fontSize = "20px";` doesn't work good for me.

Comment: I would suggest you use CSS for the purpose if you can: `*{font-size: 20px;}`

Comment: @Vivek That might not be possible when the value to be set is dynamic

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll